# HashTable<String Double>

Tags: java, double, hashtable

I have a hashtable that consists of a String and Double
`A, 8.0` is an example of what would be in it. How do I access the 8.0? Do I just go hashtable.get(A)? I'm trying to get the value of two separate keys to add them together.

```
    NodeStack myStack=new NodeStack();
    for(int i=0; i<infix.length(); i++){
        char ch=infix.charAt(i);
        if(ch=='+'){
            Character one=(char) myStack.pop();
            Character two=(char) myStack.pop();

            double first=Double.parseDouble(numbers.get(one));//, second=numbers.get(two);
            double temp=first;//+second;
            myStack.push(temp);
        }
```

Comment: Well, according to the documentation, you do that.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: Don't use the hashtable class, use a Map instead.

Comment: @hd1 `Hashtable` implements `Map`; you really mean "use another implementation of `Map`" :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access the value in a hashtable by using the get(key) method. In your case you could do the following:

```
Character one=(char) myStack.pop();
Character two=(char) myStack.pop();

String str1 = Character.toString(one);
String str2 = Character.toString(two);

double first=Double.parseDouble(numbers.get(str1));
double second=Double.parseDouble(numbers.get(str2));
double temp=first+second;
myStack.push(temp);
```

Since your hashtable key is a String you need to use a String in the get() method.

Comment: Depending on how the table is implemented, it wouldn't be needed to parse to a double :)

Comment: @NicolaiDitlevKroghKrüger true! I figured I would just stick to OP's use figuring they would know how they defined the table and can adjust as necessary.

Comment: I don't want to get the string "one" I want to get the value of "A" which is being popped from the stack. I don't know if I'm implementing the Map wrong or what, but shouldn't I be able to pop the letter off the stack, create an E object from that, then toString it, and then get the double from that String?

Comment: @kevorski I believe my edit should answer your question. If you pop a Character off the stack you need to make it into a String for the hashtable.